# Representation matrix as for Basis B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does it hold that \begin{equation*}\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\phi_a)=\left (\gamma_{\mathcal{B}}\left (\phi_a(b_1)\right )\mid \gamma_{\mathcal{B}}\left (\phi_a(b_2)\right )\mid \gamma_{\mathcal{B}}\left (\phi_a(b_3)\right )\right )\end{equation*} where $\phi_a$ is a linear function and $\gamma_B(v_i) $ is the coefficient vector of linear combination of vector $v_i$ in respect to basis B ?

Comment: If your $\phi_a$ is on a vector space with $\{b_1,...,b_3\}$ as a basis, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand on my comment. If V is a finite dimensional k-vector space with a basis $\beta = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$, then for $L\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ (a linear map on V),  $\mathcal{M}_{\beta}^{\beta}(L)$ is defined to be the unique matrix A s.t.

$A\gamma_{\beta}(v) = \gamma_{\beta}(L(v))$ $\forall v\in V$.  (1)

Write $A:= \mathcal{M}_{\beta}^{\beta}(L) = (A^1...A^n)$ which gives $AE^j = A^j$ (where $\{E^1,...,E^n\}$ is the standard basis of $k^n$). So that we can compute the $j^{th}$ column of A using (1). In particular, taking $v := E^j$ in (1) we have

$AE^j = \mathcal{M}_{\beta}^{\beta}(L)E^j = \mathcal{M}_{\beta}^{\beta}(L)\gamma_{\beta}(b_j) = \gamma_{\beta}(L(b_j))$.

(so taking $n = 3$, $L = \phi_a$, and $\beta = \mathcal{B}$, we have your equation; technically the equation (1) is defined more generally, namely $\mathcal{M}_{\beta '}^{\beta}(L)$, Lang's Linear algebra (not the introduction) is a good source for more details on that).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)